# node js chat system confliction

Tags: jquery, node.js, sockets

i can not store my chat in database neither i can see it on the browser side..
function is called upto the socket.on ... but cannot append the chat function.

```
 socket.on('new message',function(data){
        AppendNewMsg(data);
        });   


function AppendNewMsg(data){
   if($currentUserId == data.reciever){
      register_popup(data.id,data.name);
    }
    $.each($('.chat'),function(index,datax){
      if($(datax).attr('chatboxid')==data.reciever || $(datax).attr('chatboxid')==data.sender){
      if($currentUserId == data.reciever){
      $(datax).append("</br><div class='recieve'><b>"+data.name+": </b>"+data.msg+"</div>");
      $(datax).animate({scrollTop: $(datax)[0].scrollHeight}, 2000);
      }else if( $currentUserId == data.sender){
      $(datax).append("</br><div class='send'><b>"+data.name+": </b>"+data.msg+"</div>");
      $(datax).animate({scrollTop: $(datax)[0].scrollHeight}, 2000);
      }
      }
    });
  }


  </div><input size="35" chatboxid="'+ id +'" class="message" id="message_'+ id +'"></input><input chatboxid="'+ id +'" class="sendmsg" value="send" type="submit" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; border: none; padding: 0px;" hidefocus="true"></input></div></div>';

    $('body').append(element);      
    }       

            popups.unshift(id);

            calculate_popups();
    $('#message_'+ id).focus();     
        }
```

Comment: What is being passed as the `data` parameter in the `socket.on()` listener?

Comment: where is the code for emitting data to the server???

Comment: @Subham:   $(document).on( "keypress",'input.message', function(event) {   
   if (event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {   
   event.preventDefault();
   var $messageBox = $(this);
   var $reciever = $(this).attr('chatboxid');
            if($messageBox.val()!="")
            {
    socket.emit('send message', {msg:$messageBox.val(),sender: $currentUserId, reciever:$reciever});
    $messageBox.val('');
    }}
   });

Comment: please share your server side code